# How can I inject jQuery JavaScript in to react-native-webview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native-web

I can successfully render html in plain JavaScript using react-native-webview like this:

html:

```js
export const htmlTest = `
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get the distributor that is used for the authentication</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="demo" style="font-size: x-large"></p>
</body>
</html>
`;
```

js:

```js
export const jsTest = `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, World!"`;
```

App.tsx:

```
<WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: htmlTest }}
    injectedJavaScript={jsTest}
    onMessage={onMessage}
```

This works. But when I change the html to include the jQuery script:

```js
export const htmlTest = `
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get the distributor that is used for the authentication</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jsScripts/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="demo" style="font-size: x-large"></p>
</body>
</html>
`;
```

And change the `jsTest` variable to:

```js
export const jsTest = `$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#demo').html('Hello, World!');
});`;
```

I do not see the Hello, World string printed.

How can I inject the jQuery JavaScript in to react-native-webview?

Comment: do you have errors in console?

Comment: Hi, @johnSmith, no there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to inject the JQUERY library into the webview given that the content you are loading does not already load the JQUERY library (generally ff you are giving html as source rather than a url).

I have not found a way to inject the JQUERY library from a file saved on the app but I have found a way using a CDN.

First create a string to be appended to the start of the html you are adding.

const JQUERY_CDN = `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` ;

Next add the string to the source that is being passed into the webview. This will load the JQUERY library in your web view.

```
<WebView 
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: JQUERY_CDN + htmlTest }}
    injectedJavaScript={jsTest}
    onMessage={onMessage}
/>
```

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this or if there is a way for the jquery to be added from a local file.